# Notepad++ RegEx to find and replace content in comments

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to insert a line in a pattern, if it doesn't exist already. (I'm using Notepad++ for this)

This is an example of the part in a file if it is correct:

```
/* Name           */ Msg_OvVersion,
/* AccessRights   */ LGHQRead,
/* Masks          */ MSK_Diagnostics,
/* Feature        */ NoFeature,
/* Version        */ Version(2,0,0));
```

In some files the `Feature` Line is missing. If so, I need to insert it. Example for incorrect file:

```
/* Name           */ Msg_OvVersion,
/* AccessRights   */ LGHQRead,
/* Masks          */ MSK_Diagnostics,
/* Version        */ Version(2,0,0));
```

I have tried the following:

```
Replace: (\/\* Masks.*\,).*\/\* Version

With: \1\n/* Feature        */ NoFeature,\n/* Version
```

But this didn't really work, and it replaces the whole document.. am I missing something? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: there are 2 line that you are talking about `Feature'-Line` and `NoFeature`. Please share expected output?

Comment: The example above is the expected result. But sometimes the Fetaure-Line ('/* Feature        */ NoFeature,') is missing. Then the Version-Line follows the Masks-Line and the Feature-Line has to be inserted. I hope you know what I mean. I will edit to ensure clearity

Comment: where you want to insert `Feature-Line`. Please share **expected output** as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
(Masks[^\n]*)\n\/\*\s*Version
```

Replacement string:

```
\1\n/* Feature        */ NoFeature,\n/* Version
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/10)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately your regex doesn't match anything in my file. I need to find the error. Maybe there are some whitespaces which are not considered in your regex. Anyway, thanks so far!

Comment: could you post the actual file in your question.

Comment: You can find the file here and the match should be in lines 39/40: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A1561DA45433CC60!156&authkey=!ABFUbIeN3dpxcvs&ithint=file%2ccpp

Comment: try this regex `(Masks[^\n]*)\n *\/\*\s*Version`. It seems like leading spaces before `/*`

Comment: Holy moly, I would gladly vote 10x!  Allows me to keep variable text from the regex and put it back into the answer...  brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(\/\*\s+Masks\s+\*\/[^\r\n]*\r?\n)(\/\*\s+Version\s+\*\/[^\r\n]*)
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vD4eN8/3)

---

In Notepad++

Find what :

```
(\/\*\s+Masks\s+\*\/[^\r\n]*\r?\n)(\/\*\s+Version\s+\*\/[^\r\n]*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1/* Feature        */ NoFeature,\r\n$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture both *Masks* & *Version* then insert between:

```
Find:     (\*\s*Masks.*)(\r\n/\*\s*Version.*)
Replace:  \1\r\n/* Feature        */ NoFeature,\2
```

(Make sure "***.*** matches newline" is off)